# React Native, AppStore requests NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription value

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

I have an app with React Native. I've been uploading correctly to the app store, but today the app is rejected with the following message:

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to
>   the user how the app uses this data.
>
> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an
>   NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a string value explaining
>   to the user how the app uses this data.

My app doesn't use any kind of location service. The npm packages have not changed since the last version published to the app store neither have been updated, they are the same versions.

So I don't understand why Apple is saying that I am attempting to access the user location.

It is a change in the Apple Store? How can I check where is my app trying to access the user location?

This is my packages.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.5.2",
    "react-native": "0.53.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.5",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.3.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^3.8.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-video": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: We are getting the same thing with all our apps as well, starting yesterday, so I'm guessing this is a new check that Apple has introduced or something is broken on their end. We haven't changed anything as far as location services go. We never call requestAlwaysAuthorization and we have not updated any Cocoapods for quite a while now. We don't use React-Native though, so it's probably not related to that.

Comment: Might as well link to people having the same issue on Apple's dev forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/101367 https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/308460

Comment: Seems like the issue is fixed now, whatever it was. I'm able to upload builds to iTunesConnect without issue now.

Comment: I created PR for this issue but react-native still waiting for test plan! https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/19554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TylerTheCompiler has pointed in the comments, it is working again. I've uploaded the same compilation again and now the app is accepted. So it has been an issue from Apple.

Comment: We *do* use geolocation but only while the app is in use.  Our most recent submission was rejected for this reason and when I reached out to App Review with an appeal, I was told to add both permissions since my app includes the code for both in-use and always.  Feels to me as if RN will need a different solution here long-term; right now I'm crossing my fingers and re-submitting.

Answer (score 19):

Apple scan your binary for any calls to privacy related APIs as they describe [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1937/_index.html).

From the list above, the method call that triggers the requirement of NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription is `CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization`. From a quick search of my RN 0.46 codebase, this call appears in `react-native/Libraries/Geolocation/RCTLocationObserver.m` as well as in the `react-native-permissions` so even if you don't call this code from the JS, the fact that it exists in the binary will cause Apple to flag it.

The easiest solution is just to add a plist entry for NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription even though it won't ever appear to the user if you never ask for permission. I had this issue this morning uploading to the app store and after adding the flag, my app went through to review no problem.

Technically, unlinking `libRCTGeolocation` from your Xcode project should also work, although I haven't tested this so I can't guarantee that your app will still run correctly.

Comment: Unlinking `libRCTGeolocation` did fix the problem for the React Native app that I’m working on.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove RCTGeolocation.xcodeproj from your Libraries folder in the left panel of Xcode, if you are really positive you don't depend on any geo location. Removing .xcodeproj will unlink libs.

Comment: I did this as well and this worked just fine.  Our app does not use Geolocation.